# Image spot detection in android

Tags: android, opencv

I would like to ask any suggestions what would be the best algorithm , tutorials for detecting a spot (e.g. leaf spot) using android camera. I'm currently new to this. Hoping for a positive response . Thank you! And if someone has an idea about this cooperation with opencv, please i really need your help!

Comment: start looking towards opencv

Comment: I am but currently i have no idea on how can i use such algorithm for a leaf spot detection which is the one i want to develop. Please i need guides! Ty

Comment: Look for tutorials regarding opencv and blob detection. Just some generalguidelines: Make the image grey scale, play with contrast. It may be an idea to open the image in an image editor first to see what you need to do to make the spots stand out.

Comment: Welcome to SO. "Tutorials" means "Google", not "StackOverflow".

Answer (score 0):

At first take a look at [Official Documentation](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html). Then, for beginning, try a Color Segmentation approach in which you should:

1) split image to HSV panes:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
final Mat frameH = channels.get(0);
final Mat frameV = channels.get(2);
```

2) threshold the necessary color to get a binary image (e.g. yellow hue values for yellow spots):

```
Imgproc.threshold(frameH, frameH, <hue_min>, <hue_max>, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
Imgproc.threshold(frameV, frameV, <value_min>, <value_max>, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
Core.bitwise_and(frameH, frameV, thresholdMat);
```

3) dilate to fill gaps:

```
Imgproc.dilate(thresholdMat, thresholdMat, new Mat(), new Point(-1, 1), 3);
```

4) find bounding contours of areas:

```
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
Imgproc.findContours(thresholdMat, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

5) now You got contours of spots in `contours` list and You can do your magic with it:

```
Iterator<MatOfPoint> each = contours.iterator();
while (each.hasNext()) {
    MatOfPoint contour = each.next();

    // do your magic with contour here
}
```

And also don't forget filtering to remove noise of image.